# Get sum of entries over last 6 months (incomplete months)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

My data looks something like this

```
ProductNumber | YearMonth | Number
1               201803      1
1               201804      3
1               201810      6
2               201807      -3
2               201809      5
```

Now what I want to have is add an additional entry "6MSum" which is the sum of the last 6 months per ProductNumber (not the last 6 entries).
Please be aware the YearMonth data is not complete, for every ProductNumber there are gaps in between so I cant just use the last 6 entries for the sum. The final result should look something like this.

```
ProductNumber | YearMonth | Number | 6MSum
1               201803      1        1
1               201804      3        4
1               201810      6        9
2               201807      -3       -3
2               201809      5        2
```

Additionally I don't want to insert the sum to the table but instead use it in a query like:

```
SELECT [ProductNumber],[YearMonth],[Number],
6MSum = CONVERT(INT,SUM...)
FROM ...
```

I found a lot off solutions that use a "sum over period" but only for the last X entries and not for the actual conditional statement of "YearMonth within last 6 months".

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Its a SQL Database**

**EDIT/Answer**

It seems to be the case that the gaps within the months have to be filled with data, afterwards something like

```
sum(Number) OVER (PARTITION BY category 
                      ORDER BY year, week 
                          ROWS 6 PRECEDING) AS 6MSum
```

Should work.

Reference to the solution : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181773/sum-of-previous-n-number-of-columns-based-on-some-category

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If your data has gaps and youre not using a database that understands RANGE BETWEEN (i.e. youre not using oracle) you'll have to pad your data out with entries for the missing months. This isn't hard - just generate a series of negative numbers and ADD_MONTHS them to some date, then left join your data onto this contiguous set. After you do this "the last 6 rows" will be equivalnt to "the last 6 months" because there are no gaps

Comment: @Skiwan this question will likely remain unanswered until you tell us what database you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide one more option. You can use `DATEFROMPARTS` to build valid dates from the YearMonth value and then search for values within date ranges.

Testable here: https://rextester.com/APJJ99843

```
SELECT 
    ProductNumber , YearMonth , Number  
INTO #t
FROM ( values 
    (1,  201803 ,     1  ),
    (1,  201804 ,     3  ),
    (1,  201810 ,     6  ),
    (2,  201807 ,     -3 ),
    (2,  201809 ,     5  )
) s (ProductNumber , YearMonth , Number)

SELECT *
,[6MSum] = (SELECT SUM(number) FROM #t WHERE
    ProductNumber = t.ProductNumber 
    AND DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(YearMonth,4),RIGHT(YearMonth,2),1) --Build a valid start of month date
    BETWEEN 
        DATEADD(MONTH,-6,DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(t.YearMonth,4),RIGHT(t.YearMonth,2),1)) --Build a valid start of month date 6 months back
        AND DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(t.YearMonth,4),RIGHT(t.YearMonth,2),1)) --Build a valid end of month date
FROM #t t

DROP TABLE #t
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go the OUTER APPLY route.  The following produces your required results exactly:

```
-- prep data 
SELECT 
    ProductNumber , YearMonth , Number  
into #t
FROM ( values 
    (1,  201803 ,     1  ),
    (1,  201804 ,     3  ),
    (1,  201810 ,     6  ),
    (2,  201807 ,     -3 ),
    (2,  201809 ,     5  )
) s (ProductNumber , YearMonth , Number)

-- output
SELECT 
    ProductNumber 
    ,YearMonth 
    ,Number 
    ,[6MSum]
FROM #t t
outer apply ( 
    SELECT 
        sum(number) as [6MSum]
    FROM #t it
    where 
        it.ProductNumber = t.ProductNumber 
    and it.yearmonth <= t.yearmonth 
    and t.yearmonth - it.yearmonth between 0 and 6    
) tt


drop table #t
```

Comment: Simply subtracting `201712` and `201801` won't help.

Comment: how exactly does the between 0 and 6 work here in this instance?

Comment: @SalmanA is correct - you should really convert to Dates and then do a DateDiff.

Comment: @Skiwan - the Between 0 and 6 just checks that the dates are within 6 months

Comment: Try converting the yearmonth e.g. `201803` to a date using `datefromparts('2018', '03', 1)`... then use datediff to check if they are 6 months apart or less.

Answer (score 2):

Use `outer apply` and convert `yearmonth` to a date, something like this:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             convert(date, convert(varchar(255), yearmonth) + '01')) as ymd
      from yourtable t
     )
select t.*, t2.sum_6m
from t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.number) as sum_6m
      from t t2
      where t2.productnumber = t.productnumber and
            t2.ymd <= t.ymd and
            t2.ymd > dateadd(month, -6, ymd)
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

So a working query (provided by a colleauge of mine) can look like this

```
SELECT [YearMonth]
 ,[Number]
 ,[ProductNumber]
 , (Select Sum(Number) from [...] DPDS_1 where DPDS.ProductNumber = 
DPDS_1.ProductNumber and DPDS_1.YearMonth <= DPDS.YearMonth and DPDS_1.YearMonth >= 
convert (int, left (convert (varchar, dateadd(mm, -6, DPDS.YearMonth + '01'), 112), 
6)))FROM [...] DPDS
```